# How do you encrypt a message into a picture using Jython

Tags: jython, jes

I'm having problems with an assignment and am in no means looking for someone to do my homework for me.  Our professor does not answer or provide adequate resources to our questions for our assignments.  I have copied an example code that was given to us, but I am unable to make this itself run.

When I run this program all I receive in the command line is an ellipsis and nothing else.
Does anyone have an idea what the ellipsis means?
[My code and command line screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPeoQ.png)
[Screenshot of my example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbrmq.png)

Attached will be the code:

```
def encode(msgPic,original):
 # Assume msgPic and original have same dimensions
 # First, make all red pixels even
 for pxl in getPixels(original):
  # Using modulo operator to test oddness
  if (getRed(pxl) % 2) == 1:
   setRed(pxl, getRed(pxl) - 1)
 # Second, wherever there???s black in msgPic
 # make odd the red in the corresponding original pixel
 for x in range(0,getWidth(original)):
  for y in range(0,getHeight(original)):
   msgPxl = getPixel(msgPic,x,y)
   origPxl = getPixel(original,x,y)
   if (distance(getColor(msgPxl),black) < 100.0):
     # It's a message pixel! Make the red value odd.
     setRed(origPxl, getRed(origPxl)+1)
```

Below is the code that the example prompts to input into the command line:

```
- beach = makePicture(getMediaPath("beach.jpg"))  
- explore(beach)"  
- msg = makePicture(getMediaPath("msg.jpg"))  
- encode(msg,beach)  
- explore(beach)  
- writePictureTo(beach,getMediaPath("beachHidden.png"))
```

Comment: Please post all relevant code here, as text. If anyone wants to try your program, you're forcing them to retype it if it's a picture.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I believe I added the missing code you are referring to.